# Terminology: Name for the value at which a piecewise function changes which piece is "active"

Tags: functions, terminology

Consider the function $y = |x|$. It has two pieces:

1. The first is "active" for $x ≤ 0$
2. The second is "active" for $0 < x$.

$0$ is like a "tipping point" that changes which of the two pieces are active.

Is there a name for a value like $0$ in this example?

Comment: I'd suggest critical value but why  would you require such terminology?

Comment: @Karl I need to come up with a name for a variable :p `There are 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors.`

Comment: In this case, it is the 'cusp', or non-differentiable point.  But in general it may be differentiable.  Suppose you define $f(x)$ to be $x^2$ for $x <3$ and $x^2$ for $x \geq 3$.  Is $3$ the 'tipping point' you want?  There is nothing special about it in terms of the function, but only in the particular definition you gave.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yeah it's not necessarily non-differentiable, it's just the value of x that shifts the value of $f(x)$ from one piece of the function to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Breakpoint" is quite commonly used.

Comment: Can you supply any citations?

Comment: Yes:  Carl de Boor, *A Practical Guide to Splines*, (Applied Mathematical Sciences series Vol. 27), Springer-Verlag, 1987.  Also  Bartels, Beatty, and Barsky  https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Computer-Graphics-Geometric-Modeling/dp/1558604006

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest "Boundary of the intervals of definition" or "Boundary point of the intervals on which the function $f$ was piecewise defined". If you have to use this name more than a couple times, you might consider your own name for it. I have not heard any standard name however.